# Why does Mexico support Maduro?

Tags: united-states, venezuela, mexico

In [this article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/opposition-launches-protests-to-oust-maduro-as-us-venezuela-tensions-rise/2019/01/22/0416687a-1e4f-11e9-a759-2b8541bbbe20_story.html), it says that Russia, China, and Cuba support Maduro, the *de facto* president of Venezuela that the US and legitimate allies are saying is not the real one. I can somewhat understand why those countries support him—they are all vaguely allied with him and/or opponents of the US.

However, there's one strange thing: it and other sources say that Mexico's government supports him.

Why is this? Mexico is a very important ally of the US, and the two countries have a lot of trade between each other.

**How does Mexico benefit from supporting Maduro's government?**

Comment: It doesn't. Not really. But it wouldn't benefit from a puppet installed by the United States either. Hence the dilemma. Mexico wasn't for the invasion of Iraq either, but that doesn't mean they were pro-Saddam either. https://www.americasquarterly.org/content/mexicos-position-venezuela-has-always-been-about-internal-politics

Comment: Supporting a coup by a country that was vocal about not liking *your* government goes against basic self-preservation instincts.

Answer (score 1):

Mexico is in a tight spot. They are facing a lot of heat from the US, for not stopping illegal immigrants. But, they are heavily dependent on the US for trade. So, they are not going to go against US decessions strongly. So, Mexico technically supports the US decision.

But If you look at Northern Hemisphere, Chile is Burning. Brazil is struggling. Everyone knows about Argentina (which has been in distress since 2 decades?). Columbia has severe issues. All countries (Big ones) in the southern part of the hemisphere are struggling in one form or other.

There are millions of people in these countries and had been struggling. They have been suffering and expecting a stable environment to survive since mid-2015's or so. Once people come to a belief that, the situation isn't going to change any time, they are left with only one option. To migrate elsewhere. Then the mass Migration starts. But, where can they go? Only the US is the stable nation in the northern hemisphere, to which they need to go. (Canada exists, but they need to pass through the US or cross Antarctica). To reach US, they need to cross Mexico. But Crossing Mexico, to enter the US is difficult now. What happens then? Majority of these migrants will end up in Mexico. Life is already difficult in Mexico and people are finding ways to sneak into the US. What happens if the flow of migrants rises? what happens during the transition?

Russia and others support Maduro, because, they have vested interests in the supply of resources from Venezuela. Also, they need access to ports, to attack their enemies, if needed. Canada slides with the US. So is Mexico. They need a base if the war starts. They need access to ports, etc. So, they support the remaining nations, for access, if needed. Its an investment for them.

For Mexico, its do or die Situation. If they condemn Maduro, it will enrage its citizens to fight against Maduro. This could initiate migration, which they do not want. If they slide with the US and if the situation worsens, it could again trigger migration. The only way they could solve any potential upcoming issues, is by being gentle and encouraging the ruling party to be considerate to its citizens, and by encouraging Maduro to be a good leader. (Coaxing?). This way, they can delay or (possibly) aid in improvising situation in Venezuela, for the better good.

The US is not in a position to take any action on Venezuela. They have their own issues and are working hard to fix them (Trade Wars, falling jobs creation rate, inverted yield curve, Rising Poverty, etc). Acting on Venezuela now will be an expensive operation, which will drain a lot of US resources, which they don't intend to spend. So, they are just staying calm for now. They do not want to trigger anything. But they strongly oppose Maduro.

The US doesn't want to act. But the US opposes Maduro strongly. What options does Mexico have in such a situation? They just wanna Slide with Maduro, so nothing big gets triggered.

There could be other possible reasons (Bribery?) which aren't public. Also, I could have missed something too. But in my opinion, this is the primary reason.

Comment: Russia has interests in its natural resources but the U.S does not? That's funny. Also, have you considered the reason Mexico supports Maduro is because he's the democratically elected president of Venezuela?

Comment: if The US shows its interest in resources, They need to face the consequences too (Like, migration, etc), which they do not intend to, they are trying to be neutral as they have their own issues. Russia showing interest because, they always supported those who are against US. They need access to some land in northern hemisphere, in case of war. Canada, US, Mexico won't provide access to their land. Who will? That's their interest. And some access to resources. I prefer not to discuss Maduro being "Democratically elected President".

Comment: They should factor in the consequences of meddling in their "backyard". But history has shown again and again that they care very little about that. Sure, oil probably plays some role in this. But I think their objective is mainly to oust left-wing governments. After Venezuela they went after Brazil, then Equador, and now Bolivia.

Comment: Past was different. The US has its own issues now, and they are working hard to fix them. With elections in one year, and with ever-ongoing trade wars, i don't think, they would try meddling now.

Comment: Well, they are meddling. Take Venezuela and Cuba for example. There is no doubt that they're meddling there. Sanctions against those countries will mean more poverty. More poverty means more refugees.

Comment: Cuban story is old. Venezuela was doing some under the table oil trade so, They had to act. They cant exclude one member. If they do, everyone will do the same. We need to see things from others perspective too. EU was interested in buying oil from Iran. If they dont act on one, others will violate predefined rules.

Comment: The Cuban story is not old. Obama relaxed some of the sanctions which Trump just reinstated. Venezuela was doing what under the table that they had to act? I see things from the other perspective. I'm an EU citizen who is sick of the pro American propaganda we get from our bias media. Sure, the EU was interested in keeping the Iran agreement, but in the end they bowed down to Trump. Like the puppet states that they are.

Comment: Our perspectives on "Old and new", "Big and Small" differ. The US, With the NATO, Enforce a Global order and some countries trying to build their own order. I am fine with all of that. But, as per history, such independent regimes lead to war. Just imagine the destruction caused during WW2. The pain caused just for the sake of perceived power.  The scars of WW2 will remain for ever in our lives. it's wise to have one global order for all nations to avoid potential conflicts. But it should be Neutral to all. However, Some decissions were made to monetize one's power, which I am not fine with.